# Is there a way to generate a crash report locally in flutter?

Tags: flutter, crash

What I want ideally: app has a crash, it saves the crash report somewhere, and when the user opens the app again, user has the option of sending the report to someone (I'm thinking of something like use url_launcher to open an email app and copy the report into the email)

I know that there are a lot of ways monitor crashes through third-party services (like crashlytics) but I'm wondering if there is a way to do this solely from a user's device? The reason is because I want to keep my app totally free of any data-sharing if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```dart
Future<void> main() async {
  FlutterError.onError = (details) {
    FlutterError.presentError(details); // Current error
    // Implement here your logic
  };
  PlatformDispatcher.instance.onError = (error, stack) {
    // Implement here your logic
    return true;
  };
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

`FlutterError` catches errors from Flutter environment (reference: https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/errors#errors-caught-by-flutter).

`PlatformDispatcher` catches every other errors (reference: https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/errors#errors-not-caught-by-flutter).

Just implement your own logic as you wish (ex. store error to file).

Full reference: https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/errors

Comment: Thank you. One question: why does the `PlatformDispatcher.instance.onError` return `true`? What does that exactly do? Do you need to return `true` for it to work?